# When is the index of minimal submanifold finite?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $f:\Sigma^k\to M^n$ a minimal submanifold.

The Morse index of $\Sigma$ is the number of negative eigenvalues of the stability operator $L:\Gamma(N\Sigma)\to \Gamma(N\Sigma)$ acting on (smooth) sections of the normal bundle $N\Sigma$ of $\Sigma$ in $M$.

The Morse index of $\Sigma$ need not be finite in general, however, under certain conditions it is.

For example: the classical Morse index theorem says that if $\gamma:[0,1]\to (M^n,g)$ is a geodesic, then the Morse index of $\gamma$ is finite and equal to the number of points on $\gamma$ which are conjugate to $\gamma(0)$ (counted with multiplicity).

Another example: a complete oriented minimal surface in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\delta)$ with finite total curvature [has finite morse index](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/35272138.pdf).

**Question:** Suppose $\Sigma^{n-1}\subset (M^n,g)$ is a closed (compact without boundary) minimal hypersurface. Is the Morse index of $\Sigma$ finite?

If this is not true in general, which extra assumptions are sufficient to ensure the Morse index is finite?

Comment: by closed do you mean compact without boundary?

Comment: Yes. I added it to the question statement

Comment: Not completely sure, but the jacobi operator should be something like $J V = -\nabla^*\nabla V + $ lower order terms and the finiteness should follow from elliptic theory?

Comment: Yes, the second order term is given by the Laplacian on the normal bundle (see e.g. Colding-Minicozzi's book, p. 41). How are you using closedness?